# Escaping strange slash combination in string

Tags: php, preg-match

Hey guys any idea how I would go about preg matching the following string?

```
$str = "\0/";
```

I can't seem to find the correct way to escape the slashes...

```
preg_match("/\\\\\0/\\\\/", $str);
```

... is just one of may ways I've tried but all have failed.

Comment: `"\0"` is an octal zero char. See [what your string looks like](https://ideone.com/CWyQYo). The regex might look like `'~\x00/~'`. But... does it help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments using `"\0/"` means you actually have the `chr(0)` and `/` I think you meant `'\0/'` without special escaping in place.

The problem with you regex is the `/`. The regex needs to be enclosed in a delimiter it doesn't actually have to be `/`. But, which ever delimiter you use does have to be escaped in the actual regex if you want to use it. You didn't do this. The proper way would be:

```php
preg_match('/\\\\0\//', '\0/', $m);
```

or use a different delimiter:

```php
preg_match('~\\\\0/~', '\0/', $m);
```

But if you actually did want to find a regex for `"\0/"` or `chr(0) . '/'`:

```php
preg_match('/\\0\//', "\0/", $m); // or

preg_match('~\\0/~', "\0/", $m); // or

preg_match('/\0\//', "\0/", $m); // or

preg_match('~\0/~', "\0/", $m);
```

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive explanation. This solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be clear about whether `\0` represents a null byte `0x00` or the literal string of a backslash followed by a zero.

In either case, you should use [`preg_quote()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) to properly escape the literal string that you wish to match.

```php
$tgt_null    = "\0/";
$tgt_literal = '\0/';

$str_null    = "foo \0/ bar";
$str_literal = 'foo \0/ bar';

var_dump(
    preg_quote($tgt_null, '/'),
    preg_match('/'.preg_quote($tgt_null, '/').'/', $str_null),
    preg_match('/'.preg_quote($tgt_null, '/').'/', $str_literal),
    preg_quote($tgt_literal, '/'),
    preg_match('/'.preg_quote($tgt_literal, '/').'/', $str_null),
    preg_match('/'.preg_quote($tgt_literal, '/').'/', $str_literal)
);
```

Result:

```
string(6) "\000\/"
int(1)
int(0)
string(5) "\\0\/"
int(0)
int(1)
```